# Starting an App up with a different XIB

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I want to start my app up with a different Xib. How would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using interface builder:

Under SupportingFiles, in -info.plist, look for a key named "Main nib file base name".  Change that to the XIB you want it to load first

You can also take that entry out of the plist altogether an in main.m give it your appDelegate's name:

```
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"HelloViewAppDelegate");
```

Then in your appDelegate, you can manually load your first view controller based on your code and logic.  Personally, I like this better because it's much clearer to - here's my delegate and code to load it.  It doesn't have all the bindings in IB I need to remember.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    CGRect windowBounds = screenBounds;
    windowBounds.origin.y = 0.0;

    // init window
    [self setWindow: [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds]];

    // init view controller
    _mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

    [[self window] addSubview:[_mainViewController view]];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

EDIT:

Answering your comment below.  You pasted this invalid code:

```
// init view controller 
ViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init]; 
[[self window] addSubview:[ViewController view]];
```

That's not valid.  you need an instance variable name.  By referring to it as "ViewController" your attempting to call class member variables.  If your class is called ViewController then it should be:

```
// notice the instance myviewController is of type ViewController
ViewController *myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init]; 
// notice calling view against instance (myViewController)
[[self window] addSubview:[myViewController view]];
```

At this point, if it's not compiling you need to edit your question and paste your main.m and appDelegate exactly as is into the question.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x145450> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack: - I get this error message

Comment: @byranmac ViewController is which I want to override and start with.   // init view controller
    ViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    
    [[self window] addSubview:[ViewController view]]; - I get error message 'Expected identifier or '('

Comment: Im assuming ViewController is your class that inherits from uiviewcontroller?  You also need to import that header in the app delegate.  If you want to share out sample project or more code above I can take a look.

Comment: Yes. And I've already imported ViewController.h in the app delegate but still the error occurs.

Comment: If you're getting "unexpected identifier or'(' it means you have a typo - invalid syntax in your C code - likely around a (.  Can you edit your answer and append your main.m and app delegate code?

Answer (score 0):

The MainWindow.xib file is just a shell that provides the application's UIWindow. While you can put a UIViewController in MainWindow.xib, you can also just have an unconnected `UIViewController` outlet on your app delegate and pick which nib to load at runtime in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, e.g.:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options {
  if (case1)
    self.viewController = [[[MyViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
  else if (case 2)
    self.viewController = [[[MyViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
  else
    self.viewController = [[[MyViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];

  [window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
```